# How to loop through an object (evaluating three properties) and push into an array correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I need to create a function called runOnRange.
I have an object that contains three properties: a start, and end and a a step.
According to these properties it should push specific numbers to a (new) array.Once done the array should be returned.

It's beginner so no fancy techniques but loops & conditionals.

Examples - I think they explain best what is needed:

```
runOnRange({start: 10, end: 17, step: 3})
```

> // => 10 
>       // => 13 
>       // => 16

```
runOnRange({start: -6, end: -4})
```

> // => -6  // => -5 // => -4

```
runOnRange({start: 12, end: 12})
```

> // nothing should be console.logged in this case!

```
runOnRange({start: 23, end: 26, step: -1})
```

> // nothing should be console.logged in this case!

```
runOnRange({start: 26, end: 24, step: -1})
```

> // => 26  // => 25 // => 24

```
runOnRange({start: 23, end: 26, step: 0})
```

> // nothing should be console.logged in this case!

This is my code so far:

```
function runOnRange (object) {
    var arrNew = []
    var start = object.start
    var end = object.end
    var step = object.step

    //Case 1: steps betwenn start and end range
    if(start + step <= end && start + step >= start) {
        for (var i = start; i <= end; i = i + step) {
            arrNew[i]=i;
        }
    }

    //Case 2: steps not set in which case increments in one
    if (step == undefined) {
        step == 1;
        if(start + step <= end && start + step >= start) {
            for (var i = start; i <= end; i = i + step) {
                arrNew[i]=i
            }
        }
    }
    return arrNew
}
```

Running for instance

```
runOnRange({start: 10, end: 17, step: 3})
```

would lead to

```
(17) [empty × 10, 10, empty × 2, 13, empty × 2, 16]
```

in the console so there is at least one error.

Running

```
runOnRange({start: -6, end: -4})
```

leads to an empty array even though it should set the steps parameter to one and increase.

**Where do I mess up?**

Comment: `// => -26 // => -25 // => -24` why that result? the starting number is positive and the end is reachable.

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry, typo, edited

Comment: You have a typo in your case 2.   "step == 1" should be "step = 1"

Answer (score 2):

In order to not create a sparse array, you need to increment the `i` in `arrNew[i]` by *one* only, not by step - but it'd be easier to use `push`.

Even easier, I'd just a plain `while` loop, where the function takes an optional `step` parameter that defaults to 1:

```js
function runOnRange ({ start, end, step = 1 }) {
  const arr = [];
  if (step === 0) { // an odd exception...
    return arr;
  }
  let currNum = start;
  while (start < end ? (currNum < end) : (currNum > end)) {
    arr.push(currNum);
    currNum += step;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(runOnRange({start: 10, end: 17, step: 3}));
console.log(runOnRange({start: 12, end: 12}));
console.log(runOnRange({start: 26, end: 24, step: -1}));
```

Comment: Looking at the code: const and let are out of my skillset yet. Only var at this point

Comment: Using `var` or `const` or `let` makes no difference here, feel free to replace them all with `var` if you want (though, `const` and `let` should be preferable when writing code, they have fewer gotchas)

Comment: @user2132380 the object destructuring is going to blow your mind then :) Not sure this answer might be missing one nuance of a possible endless loop with this case: `runOnRange({start: 23, end: 26, step: -1})` (Note: I checked - it is indeed!)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for `runOnRange({start: 20, end: 26, step: 3})` which should be [ 20, 23, 26 ]


and `runOnRange({start: 26, end: 24, step: -1})` which should be [ 26, 25, 24 ]

Comment: Just a hint if `const` and `let` are out of OPs scope, then the `option object pattern` and `object destructuring` might be way more out of scope.

Comment: Regarding endless loop: this is why I had this in my code: if(start + step <= end && start + step >= start)

Answer (score 2):

Phew, this actually gets a bit long-winded to cover all your cases. But the essential parts are

- Use `array.push` instead of an index
- No need to repeat yourself, if `step` is undefined just set it to 1 upfront
- return early if `step` is zero
- You need to have different conditions if `step` is >0 or <0.

```js
function runOnRange(obj){
   var start = obj.start;
   var end = obj.end;
   var step = (obj.step == undefined) ? 1 : obj.step;
   var arrNew = [];
   if(step == 0) return arrNew;
   
   if((step>0 && start + step <= end && start + step >= start) || (step<0 && start + step >= end && start + step <= start)) {
        for (var i = start; (step>0 && i <= end) || (step<0 && i>=end); i = i + step) {
            arrNew.push(i);
        }
    }
    return arrNew;
}

console.log(runOnRange({start: 10, end: 17, step: 3}))
// => 10 // => 13 // => 16

console.log(runOnRange({start: -6, end: -4}))
// => -6 // => -5 // => -4

console.log(runOnRange({start: 12, end: 12}))
// nothing should be console.logged in this case!

console.log(runOnRange({start: 23, end: 26, step: -1}))
// nothing should be console.logged in this case!

console.log(runOnRange({start: 26, end: 24, step: -1}))
// => 26 // => 25 // => 24

console.log(runOnRange({start: 23, end: 26, step: 0}))
// nothing should be console.logged in this case!
```

Comment: Need to look into this @Jamiec 

Like some of your combos - didn't know one can combine things this way. The only one I don't understand is: var step = obj.step == undefined ? 1 : obj.step; What's that word by word?

Comment: It is a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and is short for `var result = booleanCondition ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse`

Comment: @user2132380 Ive added brackets to make it a little easier to read where the boolean condition is

Comment: Wow an amazing technique

Answer (score 0):

OK,

I figured, this code will do the trick. It's certainly not pretty and maybe redundant but at this point this is what I can come up with.

```
function runOnRange (object) {
    var arrNew = []
    var start = object.start
    var end = object.end
    var step = object.step

    //Case 0: handle 0 for step
    if (step === 0) {
        return arrNew
    }

    //Case 1a: steps between start and end range, start smaller then end
    if(start + step <= end && start + step >= start) {
        for (var i = start; i <= end; i = i + step) {
            arrNew.push(i)
        }
    }

    //Case 1b: steps between start and end range, start higher then end
    if(start + step >= end && start + step <= start) {
        for (var i = start; i >= end; i = i + step) {
            arrNew.push(i)
        }
    }

    //Case 2: steps not set in which case increments in one
    if (step == undefined) {
        step == 1;
        if(start + step <= end && start + step >= start) {
            for (var i = start; i <= end; i = i + step) {
                arrNew[i]=i
            }
        }
    }
    return arrNew
}
```

Comment: You'll have an endlessloop going the other way now. Its not in any of your test cases, but its there nonetheless. Check y answer.

Comment: @Jamiec thx for pointing out: can you give me an example where I would run into such a loop? Even more importantly: what would I need to alter to avoid it?

Comment: My mistake, I didnt see you had also gone the other way (split 1a and 1b). Well done you got to a solution! If you want a *shorter* solution my answer might work for you :) I do exactly the same but all in one loop.